# How can I sort by date with Nunjucks?

Tags: javascript, jinja2, nunjucks

I'm trying to use the jinja documentation to figure it out but all my attempts are failing.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#sort

Here is some test JSON data:

```
items: [{
        name: 'item 1',
        time: '2015-02-12T00:38:18.055Z'
    },{
        name: 'item 2',
        time: '2014-01-12T00:40:18.881Z'
    }]
```

How should I form the sort code so that I can sort by time?

I'ved tried:

`{% for item in items|sort%}`

and

`{% for item in items|sort(attribute='time')%}`

and

`{% for item in items|sort('time')%}`

and

`{% for item in items|sort(time)%}`

and

`{% for item in items|sort(item.time)%}`

But nothing works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Nunjucks only seems to support positional arguments:

```
{% for item in items|sort(false, true, 'time') %}
{{item.name}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

```js
var res = nunjucks.renderString("{% for item in items|sort(false, true, 'time') %}{{item.name}}<br>{% endfor %}", { items: [{
        name: 'item 1',
        time: '2015-02-12T00:38:18.055Z'
    },{
        name: 'item 2',
        time: '2014-01-12T00:40:18.881Z'
    }] });

document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/files/nunjucks.js"></script>
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Now nunjucks already supports arguments, so {% for item in items|sort(attribute='time')%} works fine

Answer (score 0):

Parse the time as Epoch time and pass it as another attribute so you can sort it.

```
items: [{
    name: 'item 1',
    time: '2015-02-12T00:38:18.055Z',
    epoch: 1232323532
}]
```

Or use a custom filter that does it automatically

Comment: There's no need for a numeric attribute value, the strings will compare fine.